# Why is my brake lever loose on my hydraulic disc brake i took my wheel off and pressed the brake now the brake lever is loose and touches the grips

Tags: mountain-bike, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

What i did in order :

- cleaned the brake pads
  -put them back in
- pressed the brake lever
- pushed the brake pads inwards
- put the front wheel on

Now as a result of this the brake lever is loose

Comment: Does your wheel spin freely or are the pads contacting the disk?

Comment: Did you have any oil leakage?

Comment: Did you get the rotor between the pads?  Or are the pads so closed up that you can't get the rotor in?   May need to separate the two pads with a plastic tyre lever.

Answer (score 4):

Oops! You should never squeeze the brakes while there is no disk between the pads. There's a plastic spacer available to slip between the pads when you have the wheel removed in order to safeguard against the condition you have created.

https://www.performancebike.com/shimano-disc-brake-caliper-pad-spacer-brm985-brm785-brm666-brm596-y8j709000/p510695

You did not specify whether the pads are contacting the rotor. If this is the case, then you've driven the pistons too close together, past the point where they should compress. Now they won't spring back. What you need to do is force those pistons apart. You need to remove the brake pads and use a thin tool, like a flathead screwdriver to force the pistons back to where they belong.

This video demonstrates:

Alternatively, you may have some air in the hydraulic line. Did you flip the bike to perform this maintenance? If so, any air in the line will migrate to the pistons. If this is the issue, once you put the bike back upright you should find that squeezing the brake lever successively will start to firm up as the air migrates back up to the reservoir on the handlebars.

No worries. Both of these are fairly common issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is something you shouldn't do with the hydrolic brakes. Don't press the brake lever when you take your tire off. How to fix it? Put the tire back on and keep pressing the brake lever. It will adjust itself after few times.